# How I can make a call QX11embedcontainer from Java?

Tags: c++, eclipse, qt, java-native-interface, qx11embedcontainer

How I can call `QX11embedcontainer` from Java?I read about JNI and , whichever functions I need to call I need to declare in java. But can i do something like by putting my application in `QX11embedcontainer` and just write `JNI` interface for only for it, which handles everything? Or I need to write Java classes for each and every C++ class respectively?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  I'd hate to have to get a QT app and a JVM working in one process - and then have to keep it working.  I'd think running the Java and QT applications in separate processes would be a lot easier as you'd only have to come up with a way for them to communicate, and that would eliminate other dependencies.

Comment: Yea you are right but, Actually I have my Qt application,  which i want to provide as plugin or as perspective to eclipse. I don't want to re-write the whole code as it takes huge amount of time.So, I was thinking that if i can embed my application in container and just write jni for that container and make a plugin from it in java? will it be helpful?

Comment: Is it a Qt GUI application?  If so, it's going to communicate directly with your display and keyboard, as will the JVM.  If that's even possible to do, it'll probably take unnatural acts of hackery that are fragile, specific to your operating system, library version(s), and probably the phase of the moon and the color of your socks.  But, it will definitely be an interesting endeavor.

Comment: yah, it is QT GUI application. and yeah it is i think goes that way ONLY! hehe.:P                    Butcan provide any suggestion on r start points from where i digg into this :/ ? tks